# Error while serializing api data : cannot be serialized to JSON because its IsReference setting is 'True'

Tags: c#, json, api, serialization

I have Create a webApi. When i run this webapi i got expected data in my browser.Here is my api get method

> public IEnumerable GetAllProducts()

```
    {
        return db.products.ToList();
    }
```

Now i want to consume this api service in my project.To do so i coded in my controller as

> public ViewResult Index()

```
    {

        var responseStream = requestMethod.GetResponseStream(requestMethod.getRequest("GET", "application/json", string.Format("{0}/api/product/", restService)).GetResponse());

        var products = deSerializeProduct<List<product>>(responseStream) as List<product>;

        return View( products);
    }
```

To serilization i have a custome serializer as:

> ```
> public class DefaultSerialization : ISerialization
> {
>     public string Serialize<T>(object o)
>     {
>         String json;
>         using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
>         {
>             var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
>             serializer.WriteObject(stream, (T)o);
>             json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
>         }
>         return json;
>     }
>     public object DeSerialize<T>(System.IO.Stream stream)
>     {
> ```

```
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));


        return serializer.ReadObject(stream);
    }
}
```

}

but while Deserializing i got error on  return serializer.ReadObject(stream); as:

> The type 'Product' cannot be serialized to JSON because its IsReference setting is 'True'. The JSON format does not support references because there is no standardized format for representing references. To enable serialization, disable the IsReference setting on the type or an appropriate parent class of the type.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible thinks you can try to work around this issue, the main reason is that EntityFramework (or ur ORM) is conflicting with serialization.

Btw, if you provide code, try to provide code which compiles and makes sence. I could not reproduce your problem since there's code missing. If you could include all the code (or even a visual studio project) I would try to fix your problem instead of demonstrating a  solution based on a totally different context.

1. In my opinion, you shouldn't be returning your ORM objects from your API. Instead return DataTransferObjects. You remove Entity Framework from the serialized objects, this way the error could disappear.
2. Use RestSharp to make REST API Calls
3. What you can do is mark your Product entity with the following attribute

   [DataContract(IsReference=false)]
4. Try using JSON.NET ?
   http://json.codeplex.com/ I'd use JSON.NET together with DTO's to achieve this.

But what I do not understand is what you are trying to achieve. Why not simply do a client side call to your API, I do not see the benefits of your server side API-call in this case. Unless your WebApi is hosted on a different environment, calling it from server side wouldn't make sense in any case. Your MVC projects seems to have reference to your ORM objects layer aswell, which again is abit strange (or is the Product class not a object mapped to ur database ?)

If they are on the same server, there is no benefit in using WebApi this way, instead create a layer which provides the information you need, and include it in both your Api and Controller, this way your controller does not need to consume the API, it can call the other layer directly. It also remove the serverside JSON deserialization.

I also notice your API returns "cities", and you are casting them to products, doesn't that sounds odd ?

EDIT: Working example:

I've created a small application which is working for me. The example can be downloaded at: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87239305/WebApi.Example.zip

I've used restSharp to create Api Calls from within .NET for both DTO and EF related objects.

**Non-DTO example:**

ApiController looks like this:

```
public interface IApiExampleController
{
    IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers();
}

public class ApiExampleController : ApiController, IApiExampleController
{
    private readonly IEFContext _context;

    public ApiExampleController()
    {
        _context = new EFContext();
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
    {
        return _context.Users.ToList();
    }
}
```

The MVC Controller to call the API looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var users = GetApiUsers();
    return View(users);
}

private IList<User> GetApiUsers()
{
    const string apiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:52812/Api/";
    const string apiSuffix = "ApiExample/GetAllUsers";

    var client = new RestClient(apiBaseUrl);

    var request = new RestRequest(apiSuffix, Method.GET);

    var response = (RestResponse<List<User>>)client.Execute<List<User>>(request);
    return response.Data;
}
```

**DTO example:**

The API controller:

```
public interface IApiDTOExampleController
{
    IEnumerable<UserDTO> GetAllUsers();
}

public class ApiDTOExampleController : ApiController, IApiDTOExampleController
{
    private readonly IEFContext _context;

    public ApiDTOExampleController()
    {
        _context = new EFContext();
    }

    public IEnumerable<UserDTO> GetAllUsers()
    {
        return _context.Users.Select(x => new UserDTO { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }).ToList();
    }
}
```

The code to call this API is the following:

```
public ActionResult IndexDTO()
{
    var dtoUsers = GetApiDTOUsers();
    return View(dtoUsers);
}

private IList<UserDTO> GetApiDTOUsers()
{
    const string apiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:52812/Api/";
    const string apiSuffix = "ApiDTOExample/GetAllUsers";

    var client = new RestClient(apiBaseUrl);

    var request = new RestRequest(apiSuffix, Method.GET);

    var response = (RestResponse<List<UserDTO>>)client.Execute<List<UserDTO>>(request);
    return response.Data; 
}
```

As you can see, there is no big difference between the DTO and EF implementation... Nevertheless, using a DTO allows you to control which data is needed on the calling side.

Both work fine (in my case), so depending on your product or city object there may not be any need to implement DTO to get rid of the error (nevertheless I advice you to do so).